# Is there some way to change this code into functional code?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream, option-type

I have this method and I imagine if there is better way to write it (like in functional programming/streams/optional mapping)? These if else doesn't look good.

```
public VerificationResult verifyToken(String token) {

    Optional<VerificationToken> verificationToken = repository.findByToken(token);

    if (verificationToken.isPresent()) {
        LocalDateTime tokeExpirationDate = verificationToken.get().getExpiryDate().plusMinutes(tokenExpiryTimeInMinutes);
        if (LocalDateTime.now().isBefore(tokeExpirationDate)) {
            return VerificationResult.VALID;
        } else {
            return VerificationResult.EXPIRED;
        }
    } else {
        return VerificationResult.INVALID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Optional` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) to keep the whole operation in the same optional chain instead of unwrapping it immediately.

```
public VerificationResult verifyToken(String token) {
    return repository.findByToken(token)
        .map(found -> found.getExpiryDate())
        .map(expiryDate -> expiryDate.plusMinutes(tokenExpiryTimeInMinutes))
        .map(tokeExpirationDate -> LocalDateTime.now().isBefore(tokeExpirationDate)
            ? VerificationResult.VALID
            : VerificationResult.EXPIRED
        )
        .orElse(VerificationResult.INVALID);
}
```

This makes more use of the `Optional` otherwise you're just treating it as a normal `null` value.

Comment: This is exactly what i meant! More you ask more you know :) Thanks